# Get index of the element nearest to the given value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The given value is 6.6. But the value 6.6 is not in the array (data below).
But the nearest value to the given value is 6.7. How can I get this position?

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[2.0, 3.0, 6.5, 6.5, 12.0],[1,2,3,4,5]],dtype=float)
```

Comment: This is also similar:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527952/nearest-neighbor-search-in-python-without-k-d-tree

Comment: @YuvalAdam looking for more direct way of doing it.@merlin2011

Comment: Can you assume the array is sorted? Please provide more detail.

Comment: @EML The index position should be exact to the original array

Comment: What do you mean by a more "direct" way? Looking at offsets seems to be the best way to do it.

Comment: i am meaning functions available in numpy or scipy@vinit_ivar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the simplest way I think.

```
>>> data = np.array([[2.0, 3.0, 6.5, 6.5, 12.0],[1,2,3,4,5]], dtype=float)
>>> data2 = np.fabs(data - 6.6)
>>> np.unravel_index(data2.argmin(), data2.shape)
(0, 2)
```

See [`np.argmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmin.html) and [`np.unravel_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy.unravel_index) function.

Answer (score 3):

You can get like this:

```
data[(np.fabs(data-6.6)).argmin(axis=0)]
```

output:

```
6.7
```

1. find the absolute diff on each element
2. Find the minimum from the result and get the element from index

EDIT: for 2d:

If it is python 2.x:

```
map(lambda x:x[(np.fabs(x-6.6)).argmin(axis=0)], data)
```

python 3.x:

```
[r for r in map(lambda x:x[(np.fabs(x-6.6)).argmin(axis=0)], data)]
```

results in returning nearest value in each row.

One value from all:

```
data=data.flatten()
print data[(np.fabs(data-6.6)).argmin(axis=0)]
```

index position from each row:

```
ip = map(lambda x:(np.fabs(x-6.6)).argmin(axis=0), data)
```

Comment: The data shape is 2d array

Comment: In your original question it was not 2d. Can you tell me you want one nearest value from all or you want minimum value for each row?

Comment: one nearest value from all

Comment: sorry that i changed into 2d because i did mistake while posting

Comment: Please find my edited answer.

Comment: i do not need for each row. one nearest value from the whole array is ok.

Comment: ok..i have edited for the same...

Comment: no no i first need the index position in 2d array, then i can get the value

Comment: one nearest index position over whole array

Comment: Please find last line of the answer...

Comment: the result should be in the form that np.where function gives the index of..

Comment: your code given [2,4] as the answer is not associated with the expected answer

Comment: yes...thats the index value of each rows. can you show me your syntax for np.where?